# Custom Compound Field with an Image/Media Field in it

Tags: media, entities

i have a question regarding the Field API and Image Fields.
I am able to create custom "compound" fields with the Field API. So afterwards, i have a Field Type, with for example 3 Textfields and 2 Checkboxes.

My question is, if its possible to add an Image Upload widget, like the one in Media, to my custom field. If so, how can i do that ?

I tried a lot in hook_field_widget_form but i need some help to get this working.

Thx in advance,
Jan